# Get the position in Angular like the jQuery position method

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

In jQuery we had the [`position()` method](https://api.jquery.com/position/):

```
$("button").click(function(){
    var x = $("p").position();
    alert("Top: " + x.top + " Left: " + x.left);
});
```

It will return the position of an element. How can I do the same in Angular?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try:

In component.html, define reference to html tag:

`<p #position>I want to go back here</p>`

In component.ts:

```
@ViewChild('position') HoldPosition: ElementRef;

clickFunction() {
  console.log(this.HoldPosition.nativeElement.offsetTop);
  console.log(this.HoldPosition.nativeElement.offsetLeft);

}
```

```

Answer (score 1):

```
document.querySelector('p').offsetTop
```

This retrieves its top position relative to its parent, and `offsetLeft` relative to the left corner.

Answer (score 0):

The answer from "Sidy Mbengue" should be selected as the solved answer. It is simple and works exactly like the jquery position() method.

To get top:

```
document.querySelector('p').offsetTop
```

To get left:

```
document.querySelector('p').offsetTop
```